# How do I create shared library using ld?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, ld

I know how to create shared libraries using `gcc` and `ln`, but how do I create a shared library using only `ld` when I have object files (from c++ or c code) as input and how do I swap onto new version of library?

Comment: Most people use `ld` through `gcc/g++` they don't invoke it directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "swap onto new version of library"?

Comment: I mean, I have liba.so.1.0.1 and I make some changes and I create new version liba.so.1.0.2. How to swap on the new version? I should just delete old connection between liba.so.1.0.1 and liba.so.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I create a shared library using only ld when I have object files (from c++ or c code) as input

You could run `gcc -v -shared ...` to discover what options `gcc` passes to `ld`. You could then pass the same arguments to `ld` directly, and you should end up with identical result.

Note: this is *ill*-advised (*don't* do this): the arguments change with different versions of `gcc` and `ld`, and they change from one OS release to the next.

It is very common to construct link lines for `ld` that used to be correct some years ago, but no longer are. The bugs introduced when doing this are often low-level and subtle, and beyond most programmers' ability to understand and fix.