# GNU Linker doesn't find a local shared library

Tags: c++, linker

I am on linux and my linker is not able to find my local libraries.

When I run

```
ld -L<path to my lib dir> OpenImageIo
```

I get

```
ld: cannot find OpenImageIO: No such file or directory
```

But libOpenImageIo is here :

```
[k.masson@hauser24 lib64]$ ll
total 7856
lrwxrwxrwx 1 k.masson k.masson      21 May  4 17:53 libOpenImageIO.so -> libOpenImageIO.so.1.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 k.masson k.masson      24 May  4 17:53 libOpenImageIO.so.1.5 -> libOpenImageIO.so.1.5.24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 k.masson k.masson 7542440 May  2 16:41 libOpenImageIO.so.1.5.24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 k.masson k.masson      26 May  4 17:53 libOpenImageIO_Util.so -> libOpenImageIO_Util.so.1.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 k.masson k.masson      29 May  4 17:53 libOpenImageIO_Util.so.1.5 -> libOpenImageIO_Util.so.1.5.24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 k.masson k.masson  499288 May  2 16:41 libOpenImageIO_Util.so.1.5.24
drwxrwxr-x 3 k.masson k.masson      27 May  4 17:18 python2.7
```

And the file seems to be correct

```
 [k.masson@hauser24 lib64]$ file libOpenImageIO.so.1.5.24 
     libOpenImageIO.so.1.5.24: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64,
     version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked,
     BuildID[sha1]=4ba0f0a40dc1287cf1a74b2530d3d0837765868b, stripped
```

I don't know why my linker doesn't find my library, I tried with other custom library and the problem is the same
Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Can you try `ld -L<path to my lib dir> -lOpenImageIo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why my linker doesn't find my library,

Because you didn't ask it to. This command:

```
ld -L<path to my lib dir> OpenImageIo
```

asks the linker to link file named (*literally*) `OpenImageIo` into `a.out`.

You probably want to do this instead:

```
gcc -o your-exe foo.o bar.o -L<path-to-lib-dir> -lOpenImageIo
```

Note that you should *almost never* use `ld` to link anything on a UNIX system. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36879855/50617) for some of the reasons.

Comment: I just tried `ld` because my compilation was returning an error :
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenimageio
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`
The problem was the way I wrote 'openimageio', **I just changed to 'OpenImageIO'** and it worked perfectly.